# How do i add two different arrays?

Tags: c

I am a newbie to C, setting up a POS terminal and i have need to be able to pass two string arrays as one

I have already successfully implemented the first array and it worked fine now i want to pass them both at the same time.

```
getListItemPrompt(&promptGames, "Games", "Diamond|Rainbow |Sky |Mercury |Jasper |Gold |Octopus |Silver");

char *gamelist[8]={"Diamond","Rainbow","Sky","Mercury","Jasper","Gold","Octopus","Silver"};

getListItemPrompt(&promptNumber, "NUMBER", "1 |2 |3 |4 |5 |6 |7 |8 |9 ");

char *numberlist[9]= {" 1"," 2"," 3"," 4"," 5"," 6"," 7"," 8"," 9"};

strmcpy(gameInfo.option.title, gamelist[2]);
//This displays "Rainbow" which works accurately

strmcpy(gameInfo.option.title, numberlist[2]);
//This displays " 2" which works accurately
```

What do i do if i want to display for example "Rainbow 2" instead of just "Rainbow" or "2"

Comment: How about using e.g. `snprintf`?

Comment: What is `strmcpy`?

Comment: strmcpy is a macro expansion of strncpy

Comment: You're not "adding arrays", you're "concatenating strings", with space in between

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `snprintf` function, which does formatting printing like `printf` except that the destination is a string instead of stdout:

```
snprintf(gameInfo.option.title, sizeof(gameInfo.option.title), "%s %s",
        gamelist[2], numberlist[2]);
```

Comment: Something to keep in mind: `sizeof(gameInfo.option.title)` will only work if `gameInfo.option.title` is declared as `char[]`, and not if it's declared as `char*`.

Comment: Okay thanks ti used this information to make headway and solve the issue.